# Compare and group rows SQL result POSTGRES

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions, window-functions

I have a table with a list of registers where each one represents an event, 
I must group this registers that have happened in the same day. 
Also I must group the events in the day, **grouping by id_fertilizer and calibrado**, but **I can't group the first result with the last ones**.

my SQL result is something like this:

```
    work_date     id_fertilizer calibrado area   begin_date    end_date
[1] '2014-07-22'  43            NULL      0      "07:03:42.0"  "07:08:00.0"
[2] '2014-07-22'  49            NULL      0      "07:08:52.0"  "07:44:04.0"
[3] '2014-07-22'  49            true      54101  "07:49:41.0"  "12:00:05.0"
[4] '2014-07-22'  49            true      4893   "12:00:30.0"  "14:06:13.0"
[5] '2014-07-22'  43            NULL      0      "14:06:51.0"  "14:49:30.0"
[6] '2014-07-22'  43            NULL      12397  "14:50:04.0"  "16:12:03"
```

where I must group the lines 3 and 4 in one line and the lines 5 and 6 in another one, taking the min() **begin_date** and max() **end_date** and sum() the **area**

lines 1 and 2 are independent lines. 
At the end I must have 4 lines: 1, 2, (3+4), (5+6)

The result I've got is something like this (using the function window), but it's wrong, because it have grouped the lines 1,5,6 in one line:

```
work_date                id_fertilizer  calibrado  area  begin_date    end_date
"2014-07-22 00:00:00.0"  43             NULL       1     "07:03:42.0"  "16:12:03.0"
"2014-07-22 00:00:00.0"  49             NULL       0     "07:08:52.0"  "07:44:04.0"
"2014-07-22 00:00:00.0"  49             true       5     "07:49:41.0"  "14:06:13.0"
```

My result, with 3 lines says the guys worked from 07:03:42 to 16:12:03 with id_fertilizer 43, but also says he worked from 07:08:52 07:44:04 with id_fertilizer 49.
It does not make sense, I must respect the chronological order of the events.
So, the result I am expecting is this:

```
      work_date     id_fertilizer  calibrado  area    begin_date    end_date
[1]   '2014-07-22'  43             NULL       0       "07:03:42.0"  "07:08:00.0"
[2]   '2014-07-22'  49             NULL       0       "07:08:52.0"  "07:44:04.0"
[3]   '2014-07-22'  49             true       58994   "07:49:41.0"  "14:06:13.0"
[4]   '2014-07-22'  43             NULL       12397   "14:06:51.0"  "16:12:03"
```

Comment: Please clean up the question. It's unclear in multiple areas. How do you aggregate `area`? You write `At the end I must have 4 lines`, just to display *3 lines*, etc. Please clarify. And add your version of Postgres as well as what you have tried (even if it's not working). Ideally also your table definition or a test case.

Comment: Thanks Erwin, I've add some more information to clarify my problem.

Comment: I updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

An educated guess:

```
SELECT work_date, id_fertilizer, calibrado
     , sum(area)       AS area
     , min(begin_date) AS begin_date
     , max(end_date)   AS end_date
FROM  (
   SELECT *
     , count(step) OVER (ORDER BY work_date, id_fertilizer, begin_date) AS grp
   FROM  (
      SELECT *
           , lag(calibrado) OVER (ORDER BY work_date, id_fertilizer, begin_date)
             IS DISTINCT FROM calibrado AS step
      FROM   tbl
      ) sub1
   ) sub2
GROUP  BY work_date, id_fertilizer, calibrado, grp
ORDER  BY work_date, id_fertilizer, calibrado, grp;
```

This produces your updated result.

Related answers with more explanation:

- [Ordered count of consecutive repeats / duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13078964/ordered-count-of-consecutive-repeats-duplicates/13079901#13079901)
- [Count number of consecutive visits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8041779/count-number-of-consecutive-visits/8042776#8042776)
- [PostgreSQL LEFT OUTER JOIN query syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15615419/postgresql-left-outer-join-query-syntax/15623256#15623256)

Comment: Hi Erwin, I've tried this solution but it does not work. I can't group by begin_date. Also, if I remove the begin_date it does not work how I was expecting. I could not understand the logic of this selec.

Comment: @ViníciusCR: My solution does not group by `begin_date`. Read the answers I linked to for explanation on the used techniques.